# Is there a way to prevent JSON.stringify from calling toJSON?

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

JSON.stringify has a feature to enable objects to define their own serialization by defining a function with the name toJSON.

Here is the excerpt from MDN docs:

> toJSON() behavior
>
> If an object being stringified has a property named toJSON whose value
>   is a function, then the toJSON() method customizes JSON
>   stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the
>   value returned by the toJSON() method when called will be serialized.

Is there a way to override it, so that even if there are toJSON methods attached, it ignores them and does the 'normal' serialization?

Reason: There are some toJson methods, having minor bugs, introduced in my environment due to a JS library. And some of those buggy serialized formats have been accepted and server-side is coded to that format.

So, I am stuck not being able to remove the buggy methods, however I would like to hint JSON.stringify to ignore those methods going forward.

Comment: Not going to post this as an answer because I'm ashamed of having even tried this, but you can override the method: https://jsfiddle.net/TheQueue841/6ynwmy5t/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the method:

```
var fn = JSON.stringify;

JSON.stringify = function (o) {
  var tmp, toJSON;    

  if(o.toJSON){
    toJSON = o.toJSON;
    o.toJSON = undefined;    
  }
  tmp = fn.apply(this, arguments);
  toJSON && (o.toJSON = toJSON);
  return tmp;
};
```

Comment: Thanks.. it looks promising. I'll try it out

Comment: Be careful that it does not work if `toJSON` is defined on the prototype like `Array.prototype.toJSON`. You need to delete it here too.

Comment: @SébastienDeprez I edited the code to reflect that note as I too discovered the inheritance issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you null a `toJSON` property in your object it will get back to default behavior

```
obj.toJSON = null;
```

If you don't want to modify your object you can make a copy of it before

```
var copy = Object.assign({}, obj);
obj.toJSON = null;
```

Comment: `null` values are also serialized, better use `undefined`. And it depends on how this method is attached to the Object. Object could be frozen, the property may be `writable:false` or `configurable:false`, and maybe a few more possibilities to disable overwriting the method.

Comment: This doesn't work with frozen objects nor does it work recursively.